# Keep Getting a Segmentation Fault On This?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, radix-sort

I keep getting the segmentation fault (core dumped) on the code below.  Any ideas on why this is happening.  The code is designed to read numbers from a text document, convert them to integers, perform radix sort, and print out the array.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int getMax(int arr[], int n)
{
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
    return max;
}

void countSort(int arr[], int n, int exp)
{
    int output[n];
    int i, count[10] = {0};
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]++;
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        output[count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10] - 1] = arr[i];
        count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]--;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = output[i];
}

void radixsort(int arr[], int n)
{
    clock_t clockStart;
    clockStart = clock();

    int m = getMax(arr, n);
    for (int exp = 1; m / exp > 0; exp *= 10)
        countSort(arr, n, exp);

    cout << "\nTime taken by radix sort: " << (double)(clock() - clockStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
}

int StrToInt(string sti) 
{
    int f;
    stringstream ss(sti); //turn the string into a stream
    ss >> f;
    return f;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10000];
    int i = 0;
    int result;
    string line = "";

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("integers2.txt");
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(!myfile.eof())
        {
            getline(myfile, line);
            result = StrToInt(line);
            arr[i] = result;
            //cout<< arr[i] <<"\n";
            i++;
        }
    }


    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    radixsort(arr, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Contents of the text file I am using for input:
1244
3455
6565
55
765
8768
687
879

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger to identify where in the code the segfault happens?

Comment: No I am new to C++, just now learning

Comment: The contents of the file are numbers in a list like: 1024 3456 4758 6879

Comment: `while(!myfile.eof())` is a bad idea.

Comment: This doesn't crash, but I had to make some changes since my compiler of choice does not support variable size arrays. Not sure where your problem is. http://ideone.com/520c9A This is more like your code without the file reading and it also doesn't crash. http://ideone.com/9vN0Sq Did you really mean to sort all 10k elements?

Comment: I think it is something to do with the way I converted the characters to integers before storing them in an array.  The actual input document has 1000s of numbers, but I am just testing on this smaller sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior, because it uses more entries of the array than you initialized with data. You pass the length of the entire array for `n` even though only a small portion of it, from `0` to `i`, has been initialized.

Change the code to use `n` in place of `i` in the reading loop, and pass that `n` unmodified to the sort function. This is going to fix the problem ([demo](http://ideone.com/wfXxsl)).

```
int n = 0;
myfile.open("integers2.txt");
if(myfile.is_open()) {
    while (myfile >> arr[n]) {
        n++;
    }
}
radixsort(arr, n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your working code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int getMax(int arr[], int n)
{
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
    return max;
}

void countSort(int arr[], int n, int exp)
{
    int output[n];
    int i, count[10] = {0};
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]++;
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        output[count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10] - 1] = arr[i];
        count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]--;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = output[i];
}

void radixsort(int arr[], int n)
{
    clock_t clockStart;
    clockStart = clock();

    int m = getMax(arr, n);
    for (int exp = 1; m / exp > 0; exp *= 10)
        countSort(arr, n, exp);

    cout << "\nTime taken by radix sort: " << (double)(clock() - clockStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
}

int StrToInt(string sti) 
{
    int f;
    stringstream ss(sti); //turn the string into a stream
    ss >> f;
    return f;
}

int main()
{
    const int MAX_SIZE = 10;

    int arr[ MAX_SIZE ] = { 0 };

    //int i = 0;
    //int result = 0;
    string line = "";

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("integers2.txt");
    if(!myfile.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Could not open file!\n";
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Reading integers...\n";

    int index = 0;
    //while ( index < SIZE && getline( myfile, line ) )
    while ( index < MAX_SIZE && myfile >> arr[ index ] )
    {
        //getline( myfile, line );
        //result = StrToInt( line );
        //arr[index] = std::stoi( line );
        cout << arr[index] <<"\n";
        index++;
    }

    cout << "Sorting integers...\n";

    //int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    radixsort( arr, index );

    for ( int i = 0; i < index; i++ )
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Some points:**

1. Check [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) for string to integer conversion; BTW, you don't need to do that. Just read it directly like this: `while ( file >> integer )`.
2. Need to check if the file is open; return ERROR otherwise; in your case, the rest of the code was executing anyway even if the file was not open i.e. code after `if ( myfile.open() ) { ... }`
3. `while( !myfile.eof() )` is bad practice. See: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)
4. You don't need to calculate the size like `int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);` because you already know the size. Just use a `const` for this.
5. While reading from file, you also need to validate the maximum size of your array. You should read what the size allows you. Take care of `out-of-bounds` read / write errors.
6. Use `<ctime>` instead of `<time.h>`.